# Bypass selenium bot detection

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

Hello I wanted to automate purchasing on some websites using Requests, Selenium, and Chrome driver. It works on most sites but on some sites they instantly detect that I am a bot, and cut off my access to the site. I have searched through forums to try and find a solution but they are mostly all outdated methods. So far this is my code for starting the web browser.

```
auto = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
auto.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
auto.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=auto,
                    executable_path='path/to/driver')
```

what'd i'd like to do would look something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=19&v=2gZi5IxmTMM&feature=emb_logo

Comment: Take the hint... they don't want your bot on their site.

Comment: In addition to what @JeffC said, I can't imagine that there is a universal solution to this.